# Proving $\tan^2(\theta)=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am doing the question that requires me to prove $\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ given$$\cos(\theta)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin(\alpha),\ \sin(\theta)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin(2\alpha).$$
I managed to show that $\tan(\theta)=\sqrt{4-3\cos^2(\theta)}$, then $\tan^2(\theta)+3\cos^2(\theta)=4$. I am stuck when I proved this.

After that, I went on the find the mark scheme of this question, it said that by having
$$\tan^2(\theta)+3\cos^2(\theta)=4\tag1$$
we can deduce that:
$$(\tan^2(\theta)+1)(4-\tan^2(\theta))=3\tag2$$
Then, the required result is proven.

How can (1) be factorized in the form of (2)? And how does (2) confirm the result?

Thank you so much for your help.
update:
Sorry guys. We should prove for $tan^2(\theta)$ instead of $tan(\theta)$. I typed it wrongly.

Comment: I find that getting to $(2)$ is a bit circular. You would be better off multiplying both sides by $\cos^2 \theta$ and solving the quadratic equation to find the value of $\cos^2 \theta$, from which you can find $\tan \theta$.

Comment: An easier way is to square the given equations and add them. LHS becomes 3/4 .now find sin(alpha) and then cos alpha. Note that tan(x)=sin(2alpha)/sin(alpha)=2cos(alpha)

Comment: Thank you guys. I am trying the methods that you guys provided. That's much help. But I really really want to know why does (2）confirms the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\cos^2 \theta=\dfrac{1}{\sec^2 \theta}=\dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2 \theta}$, to obtain (2).
Solve the quadratic; the positive root is $\tan^2 \theta$; its positive root in turn is $\tan \theta$.

Comment: Thank you, but for (2), the RHS is not equal to 0. I don't know how to solve the quadratic when in this form...

Comment: @HenryCai $(p^2+1)(4-p^2)=3 \iff p^4-3p^2-1=0$

Comment: ...I didn't notice that. Thank you very much. Now I finally get this